# Create new iOS app version in iTunes connect with Fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane, fastlane-produce

Is there a way to create a new iOS app version for an already existing app in iTunes Connect using fastlane?

I tried using the following `produce` command:

```
produce create -a "com.somebundleidentifier" -q "My App Name" -u test@example.com -b XXXXXX -d -z 6.2.4
```

But I get back:

```
[iTC] App 'com.somebundleidentifier' already exists (983959158), nothing to do on iTunes Connect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using [`deliver`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver) when you upload the `ipa`.

```
deliver --ipa "$ipa" -z 6.2.4 -u test@example.com
```